# How do I build a specific citation call-out style using the 'abbrv' bib style? I use the 'natbib' package

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, bibliographystyle

I use

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
```

I also have the following reference:

```
@article{RN22,
   author = {Liu, Shiang-Tai and Kao, Chiang},
   title = {Fuzzy measures for correlation coefficient of fuzzy numbers},
   journal = {Fuzzy Sets and Systems},
   year = {2002},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

How can I cite this reference as `Liu and Kao [22]` instead of as "just" `[22]`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 2):

The ancient `abbrv` bibliography style can only generate pure numeric-style citation call-outs. Fortunately, since you already employ the `natbib` citation management package, an easy solution is at hand: First, change

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
```

to

```
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
```

`abbrvnat` is natbib's reimplementation of the venerable `abbrv` style, with some useful add-ons such as recognizing and knowing what to do with fields such as `url` and `isbn`. (Instead of `abbrvnat`, one could also use the `plainnat` or `elsarticle-num-names` bib styles -- and probably a few others as well.)

Second, be sure to use `\citet` -- not `\cite`, and not `\citep` either -- go create citation call-outs.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{RN22,
   author  = {Liu, Shiang-Tai and Kao, Chiang},
   title   = {Fuzzy measures for correlation coefficient 
             of fuzzy numbers},
   journal = {Fuzzy Sets and Systems},
   year    = {2002},
   type    = {Journal Article}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{RN22}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `elsarticle-num-names` over natbib's own `abbrvnat`?

Comment: @DaiBowen - You're right. It so happens that I'm quite familiar, due to my own work, with the `elsarticle-num-names` bib style, so that's what my mind glommed on to right away. However, as long as `\citet` is used, the `abbrvnat` and `plainnat` bib styles will also get the job done. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sure, `\citet` and any `natbib`-compatible style should do the job with the `numbers` option to `natbib`.